# Show bigger dots when same values are plotted

Tags: r

When I plot the following example:

```
Participant <- c(1:12)
AnswersDay1 <- c(9,3,9,13,7,12,10,7,9,0,12,11)
Day1Group   <- c(0,1,0,1, 0, 1, 0,1,0,1, 0, 1)


PushFrame <- data.frame(Participant, AnswersDay1, Day1Group)
plot(AnswersDay1, Day1Group)
```

The plot shows only ten dots instead of the 12 values in the data.frame. I figured out that this is due to the fact, that there are three pairs with the exact same value.

Is it possible to somehow illustrate this inside the plot? Maybe that bigger dots are used when they have the same value or something like this?

Comment: Make a [hexbin](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hexbin/index.html) plot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1) sunflowerplot** You may prefer to use a sunflowerplot which shows duplicate points as a single point with a spoke for each occurrence.  No packages needed.

```
sunflowerplot(AnswersDay1, Day1Group)
```

(continued after graph)

[image: screenshot]

**2) jitter** The other common technique is to use jitter which slightly moves duplicate points.  In this example we jitter the Y variable but one could alternately jitter the X variable or both.  No packages needed.

```
set.seed(123) # set seed of random number generator for reproducibility
plot(AnswersDay1, jitter(Day1Group))
```

(continued after graph)

[image: screenshot]

**3) cex** If you really do want to use size as an indicator of how many duplicates then create a new data frame which contains the number of duplicates of each point (in the Participant column of ag) and then plot as shown.  Again, no packages needed.

```
ag <- aggregate(Participant ~., PushFrame, length)
plot(Day1Group ~ AnswersDay1, ag, cex = Participant, pch = 20)
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there’s absolutely a way of doing this: set the `cex` appropriately:

```
plot(AnswersDay1, Day1Group, cex = point_size)
```

How do you get the point size corresponding to each entry? Well, you count them using `table`:

```
tab = table(AnswersDay1, Day1Group)
```

This is what `tab` looks like:

```
           Day1Group
AnswersDay1 0 1
         0  0 1
         3  0 1
         7  1 1
         9  3 0
         10 1 0
         11 0 1
         12 1 1
         13 0 1
```

That is, for each data point in `AnswersDay1` it tells you how often that point appears. Now you just need to index it using `AnswersDay1` and `Day1Group`:

```
point_size = diag(tab[as.character(AnswersDay1), as.character(Day1Group)])
```

Note the `as.character` — this is necessary since the names in the table are character strings, and using numeric indices here would index the wrong element. `diag` gives us back just the diagonal of the resulting matrix, which is what we’re after here.

Comment: also an excellent answer - too bad that i can't accept both! :(

Answer (score 3):

you can use the `scales` package to alter transparency of your points, then overlapped points will be brighter (less opulent):

```
 library(scales)
 plot(AnswersDay1, Day1Group, pch = 20, cex= 2, col = alpha('black', 0.35))
```

the `alpha` parameter varies from 1 (no transparency) to 0 (complete transparency).

[image]

Comment: No need for the `scales` package to do this.

Comment: @KonradRudolph could you elaborate

Comment: Alpha channel colours are a feature of base R, you don’t need the `scales` package for them. Your above code for instance is equivalent to using `'#00000060'`. And `scales` internally also only uses core R functions (to with, `col2rgb` and `rgb`) to add transparency.

Comment: @KonradRudolph okay, thank you, i didn't know that. it looks like using `scales` is less fiddly than messing about with colour shades though

Answer (score 2):

A couple more possibilities:

@KonradRudolph's solution is already implemented in `plotrix::sizeplot()`.

```
PushFrame <- data.frame(Participant=1:12,
     AnswersDay1=c(9,3,9,13,7,12,10,7,9,0,12,11),
     Day1Group=c(0,1,0,1, 0, 1, 0,1,0,1, 0, 1))


 library(plotrix)
 with(PushFrame,sizeplot(AnswersDay1,Day1Group))
```

In `ggplot2`, `stat_sum()` automatically counts coincident values and scales the size accordingly ...

```
 library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
 ggplot(PushFrame,aes(AnswersDay1,Day1Group))+stat_sum()
```